# What is the most isolated building in the world?

Tags: where-on-earth, factoids, architecture, remote-locations

I wish to know what the the most isolated building in the world is, with "most isolated" being defined as "the longest distance to the closest building". Building complexes count as multiple buildings. A building is defined as any permanent man made structure that is used either for habitation or human activities. So this includes houses, office buildings, fixed rocket launch sites, military bases embedded into mountains,... Essentially everything apart from walls and other fortifications, small outdoor sheds not meant for living or working like outhouses or storage sheds and wells. For example: the Svalbard seed vault is considered a building, BUT it lies a couple hundred meters from the Svalbard airport, so it's not the most isolated building in the world.

---

Clarifying the comments: (Ant)Arctic research stations count as multiple buildings if they're modular like Halley VI. If they're 1 contiguous building, they're counted as 1 building. Tents don't count as permanent. I don't know enough about igloos to know how permanent they are, but let's say they don't count. Seldom inhabited radio stations count.

My own research has pointed towards the lighthouse on a remote island off the coast of Cornwall to be a likely contender, since it's 70 kilometers away from the nearest building.

Answer (score 23):

IMPORTANT NOTE: From comments we have a photographic proof that in recent years there were two buildings (but in the same platform), so this answer do not fulfil the question requirements (later precised: *Arctic research stations count as multiple buildings* [which are similar to this]). (Until nature will destroy this station, and maybe a new one-single building will be constructed).

I suspect sometime the most isolated building is a hut/radio station on [Bouvet_Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouvet_Island). Note: In theory, they also have an internet top domain (.bv).

Looking from Wikipedia and maps, I'm not sure there is only one single building, but it seems so.  Note (from Wikipedia), sometime buildings were destroyed, and years later rebuilt. They may be inhabited for few months from time to time. So I assume, when the building is not destroyed by nature, it is the most remote building.

Why do I suggest the hut/radio station on this island? This island is the most remote place on Earth, so there is a good possibility that it also has the most remote buildings (also because I found no references that Bouvet ever had 2 or more huts).

Comment: I don't know if there are further buildings on the island, but the current research station is itself separated into two buildings. At least I would consider it as two separate buildings, although they are placed on the same plattform: https://www.npolar.no/norvegia/

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: you are right. Note for other: there is also the same page in English (look on top right).

Comment: Well, for some odd reason, your obviously incorrect answer is still gaining a lot of up-votes. Perhaps you should correct it or delete it instead of letting it stand?

Comment: Not in theory, the ccTLD exists: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/bv.html ; there might be no registrations in it, but the TLD exists, see `dig bv. NS`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek There are no registrations, you can't register a domain with that TLD and there are no plans to open the TLD for registrations, so it has absolutely no practical significance that it "exists".

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo You can also say exactly the same thing for any TLD about to open like the recent 2012 gTLD round before they started, or even  `ss` right now. So `bv` exists as a TLD (see IANA website or the rootzone), whether it has registrations or not is irrelevant to the fact it exists, hence the "in theory" in the answer is wrong. It is not in theory, it exists in practice.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica But why? Any domain at any place in the DNS tree can exist without anything below. You are just creating new definitions. The `bv` domain (TLD) exists because if you query a root nameserver for it it does not say `NXDOMAIN` (domain does not exist) but gives back a reply. This is a proof of technical existence. You can instead choose any other definition that suits you, but the technical facts remain that this TLD exists.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica "TLD exists as a concept"  completely wrong. `bv` exists in practice, see the root zone or query a root nameserver.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the further explanation. I agree. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: That's where RoyG hosts his website.

Comment: So are we saying that if there is one hut on this island it is clearly the most remote building, but as soon as they put up another hut next to it, it immediately loses this title and becomes no more remote than my garden shed? That seems a bit odd...

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I added a big note at beginning of the answer, about your comment/link: there are in fact two buildings.

Comment: Are both buildings meeting the new rule that storage buildings (sheds) do not count?

Comment: @Willeke I think the question has become so unclear, that it can't be answered. Sheds are not supposed to count, but without further explanation, OP also 'clarifies' that 'arctic research stations count as multiple buildings'. I am not sure if the distinction between arctic and antarctic research stations is intentional and why a single building per his definition should 'count as multiple buildings' just because it is a research station.

Comment: @OscarBravo That is the definition that OP went with - building furthest removed from other buildings.

Comment: Would a lander on the moon count?

Answer (score 16):

It may well be the **Earhart Lighthouse** on **Howland Island**, smack dab in the middle of the Pacific about 3000 km from Hawaii:

[image]
(Courtesy [Joann94024](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Joann94024), Wikipedia)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howland_Island

https://maps.app.goo.gl/wHMGRizq7uqzYeaD9

Built in 1937 for Amelia Earhart's attempt to cross the Pacific and promptly abandoned.  It's not entirely clear if it was ever really a habitable lighthouse, but it certainly is a "structure for human activities", and on casual inspection I can't find any other structures for hundreds of miles around.  (Baker Island is not far away, but it appears to contain nothing at all.)

Comment: According to the Wikipedia there is a lighthouse on Baker Island (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_Island)

Comment: There are things on baker island. http://desertedplaces.blogspot.com/2017/03/baker-island-deserted-atoll-in-pacific.html and https://goo.gl/maps/f7Lq9XFoJEbFZbJT6

Comment: @simon Curses!  Jarvis Island might be a better bet then, but I'll let people poke at this for a while before I rewrite the answer. https://goo.gl/maps/cNSfMdDJYPNxPkQFA

Comment: I'm confused (noting this because you prominently mentioned it) that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelia_Earhart#Nearing_Howland_Island) makes no mention of the lighthouse being *[b]uilt for Amelia Earhart's attempt to cross the Pacific*. The Wikipedia article states instead that a warship was used for intended guidance using the ship's radio equipment. [The section on the lighthouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howland_Island#Earhart_Light) states it was *named* (when?) for Amelia Erhart but does not list its purpose as instrumental in the event (nor the year it was built).

Comment: "not entirely clear if it was ever really a habitable lighthouse": habitable?  Do you see the size of the doorway?  But lighthouses aren't generally inhabited; keepers typically lived (when lights typically had keepers) in an adjacent building.

Comment: Is that an Amazon delivery I see in the bottom-left of the image?

Answer (score 5):

Answers to this type of question generally hinge upon exact meaning or interpretation of words.  In this case "isolated", "building" and "in the world" seem to be key.

Since the concepts of isolation and what constitutes a building have already been discussed it seems relevant to address what "in the world" means.  Taken literally it seems to imply within the planet earth, or under the surface.  However, I suspect Glorfindel had a broader meaning in mind.  Therefore, considering from a wider perspective, I'll expand my answer to include our entire solar system.  With that in mind, the most remote structure which has helped house humans and remains intact to this day would be one of the NASA Apollo mission lunar landers.

There are 6 Apollo landing sites.  Based on their distribution it appears that the Apollo 15 mission was the most remote.  At each site the lower half of the lunar module along with many scientific instruments and whatever they no longer needed was left behind.  This reduction of weight allowed the astronauts to maximize the amount of lunar samples they brought back.  At the Apollo 15 landing site an electric lunar roving vehicle was also abandoned.

[image: Apollo 15 lunar lander habitat structure]

[image: Map of all 6 Apollo landing sites]

Comment: Sorry, I explicitly meant on Earth. Not in the solar system, just on our planet.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of [jcklopp's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/160974/130753)—

The part of the Apollo LEM which housed humans was the ascent stage, which ascended; the landing sites on the moon contain only the landing stage and various equipment, which probably wouldn't count as buildings.

Most of the ascent stages are destroyed, except Snoopy (which never landed) and possibly Eagle.

- Snoopy never landed on the moon, but housed humans for 8 hours and is now in a heliocentric orbit; if that counts, it's definitely the most isolated.
- Otherwise, the Eagle housed humans for over 24 hours, of which 21½ on the moon, including a sleep period, and may still be in a lunar orbit.

Both of these date to the 1960s, over 50 years ago; that may count as "permanent" by human standards, depending on the state they're in — whether they're still essentially serviceable (perhaps with a resupply and repair) or more akin to wrecks.